# Magnific Popup queda detras de modal

Tags: jquery, imagen, modal, magnific-popup

Estoy utilizando la libreria Magnific Popup (que es para mostrar imagenes desde un un thumbnail con zoom, etc), la cuestion es que puedo implementarla bien, el problema esta que mis imagenes estan dentro de un modal, a la hora de usar la libreria, esta queda detras del modal asi:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como puedo hacer para que el elemento quede adelante del modal o como puedo cerrar el modal al hacer click alguna imagen? (no es la opcion que mas deseo pero tocara)

Este es el codigo que estoy utilizando:

```
$('.zoom-gallery').magnificPopup({
    delegate: 'a',
    type: 'image',
    closeOnContentClick: false,
    closeBtnInside: false,
    autoFocusLast: true,
    mainClass: 'mfp-with-zoom mfp-img-mobile',
    image: {
        verticalFit: true,
        titleSrc: function (item) {
            return item.el.attr('title') + ' &middot; <a class="image-source-link" href="' + item.el.attr('data-source') + '" target="_blank">image source</a>';
        }
    },
    gallery: {
        enabled: true
    },
    zoom: {
        enabled: true,
        duration: 300, // don't foget to change the duration also in CSS
        opener: function (element) {
            return element.find('img');
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo solucione cerrando el modal al momento del click en la clase del `zoom-gallery` asi:

```
$('.zoom-gallery').click(function () {

    $('#modalFotos').modal('hide')
});
```